# Facebook API : How to display user's name whitout auth?

Tags: facebook, api

My question is very simple

On this page: http://www.facebook.com/axefan?sk=app_116526158422952

How did they do to show the names of the connected user, without asking permission? I thought it was not possible to have UID of a member without going through auth?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need an access token to get the name of something in Facebook. You just need the id of whatever it is you are checking (Person, page, event, etc).

For example, you can check these without appending any access token to the URL:

http://graph.facebook.com/595869823?fields=id,name

http://graph.facebook.com/292378408255?fields=id,name